# Variable that can be used in all ajax settings

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following:

```
$('.fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    add: function(e, data) {
        ...
    },
    done: function(e, data) {
        ...
    }
});
```

What I need to do is be able to use the following between all ajax settings (`add`, and `done`):

```
var form = $(this).closest('form');
```

How would I use that variable in the function call so it can be used between all options?

Answer (score 0):

The context (`this`) in callbacks(add,done,..) refers to you jquery object `$('.fileupload')`

So :

```
$('.fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    add: function(e, data) {
        var form = $(this).closest('form');
    //...
    },
    done: function(e, data) {
        var form = $(this).closest('form');
 //..
    }
});
```

**UPDATE :**

If you want to instantiale `form` jquery object only once, you must instantiate it outside then , you can use it on all callbacks(=settings)

**EXAMPLE :**

```
$('.fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    add: function(e, data) {
        console.info(myForm);
    },
    done: function(e, data) {
        console.info(myForm);
    }
}).closest("form").cache('myForm') ;
```

Known that cache is a jquery plugin :

```
$.fn.cache=function(varName){var that=this;
    setTimeout(function(){window[varName]=$(that);},0);}
```

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to only call it once.

Comment: You cannot because a callback is a function which has implementation . there is no passing code between implementation

Comment: Why the `setTimeout()`? And why pass a string that creates a global variable named `varName` that gets assigned a jQuery object referencing `window`?

Comment: it is wrong . i have update it since few sec.And don't worry about setTimeout because timeout=0 . thanks anyway

Comment: Alright, but the global variable you're creating is still holding a jQuery object that references the `window` object. I'm not seeing the point, or the point of using `setTimeout` in the first place.

Comment: It is for reflection . I invite u to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21542060/understanding-javascript-settimeout-and-setinterval

Comment: Look at the first comment under that question. I understand how it works. Doesn't change the fact that your global variable isn't holding the form. `setTimeout` doesn't have anything to do with reflection. I think you're not understanding how `this` works in JavaScript, or what `setTimeout` is used for.